# using shell script to automate git commits and ssh apache server deployments?

Tags: git, apache, shell, ssh

I'm trying to figure out how I go about automating this process using a script.

I don't know what I'd use, or how to go about it. I'm looking to get pointed in the right direction.

**In git :**

```
git commit -am "my commit"
git pull origin my_branch
git push origin my_branch
git archive --format zip --output /c/git/(environment)_(date)_(commithash).zip my_branch
scp (environment)_(date)_(hash).zip root@12.3.4.56:/var/www/html-(domain)
password123
```

**In apache :** ( usually i putty in... )

```
root
password123
cd /var/www/html-(domain)/(environment)
unzip ../(environment)_(date)_(commithash).zip
n
n
A
cd ..
cp -pr (environment) (environment)_(date)_(commithash)
exit
```

To explain whats going on, I am pushing my latest commit, SCPing to apache server docroot, deploying, and making backup with commit hash.

Comment: You don't want sh, you want make.

Comment: Look into [Expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm), which can easily automate repetitive tasks for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a shell script as you plan to -- just save the commands you want to run (one per line) in a file, add `#!/bin/bash` at the top, make it executable with `chmod +x myscript.sh` (the `.sh` file extension is not required) and then run it with `./myscript.sh`.

You may find it easier to use scaffolding that specifically assists with deployment. A nice-looking one of these systems (that I have yet to try) that uses shell scripts is [`deliver`](https://github.com/gerhard/deliver).

Comment: You can create the Windows equivalent, a Powershell script. I found an example for [deployment using Powershell](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16768/Deployment-made-simple-using-Powershell), but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the first step toward [Continuous Integration](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html).

I use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) which I set up to do:

- git pull origin master
- run unit tests
- deploy code
- run db deployments
- update ticket system with success/fail

There are lots of extensions and tools as well, works with any language, etc.